# Flex/AS3: removing item from ListCollectionView

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I used a temporary array to populate a ListCollectionView. Later, I have a screen that displays a DataGrid using the ListCollectionView as a dataProvider. The user can delete a row in the DataGrid by selecting the row then clicking a Delete button.

How can I access the original source that ListCollectionView uses, and delete the item from there?

After I do that, will the item also be deleted from the ListCollectionView automagically, and no longer be shown in the DataGrid (or does something need to be refreshed)?

UPDATE 1

Does the following sound like I'm on the right track? (I want to remove it from the source (is that the ".list"?) of the ListCollectionView, not just from ListCollectionView.)

```
[Bindable] private var _myLCV:ListCollectionView=new ListCollectionView(new ArrayList());
...
var obj:Object = _myLCV.getItemAt(myGrid.grid.selectedIndex); // get item user selected
_myLCV.list.removeItemAt( _myLCV.list.getItemIndex(obj) );   // delete item from source
```

UPDATE 2

I'm not sure why (I'm using SDK 4.5.1A), but I seem to need to add the following line of code to the above code in UPDATE 1, for the DataGrid to reliably update and show the deleted row:

```
_myLCV.refresh();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My impulse is to recommend deleting the item from the ListCollectionView using [removeItemAt](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#removeItemAt%28%29).

If you truly want to access the source instead of dealing with the collection, then it depends what type of ListCollectionView you're using.

If you're using an ArrayCollection you can access the source using the [source property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html#source).
IF you're using an XMLListCollection, you can access the source using the [source property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/XMLListCollection.html#source).

There isn't an inherent source property in the ListCollectionView, but the [List property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#list) may suffice.

In any case, removing an item from the ListCollectionView or the ListCollectionView's source should automatically update the DataGrid.  IF not, you can call the [refresh() method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#refresh%28%29) on the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Spark DataGrid, like other list base controls such as List or even DataGroup, would observe change events from its dataProvider.  The change events may include item removal, update, sort and insertion.  This provides the convenience of updating the control by just updating its underlying data.

That said, if your intent is to "refresh" the datagrid to stay up to date with the LIstCollectionView, by modifying the array and then refresh would rather be unnecessary.

Comment: In practice (using my UPDATE1 code above), I'm observing the DataGrid intermittently still shows the removed item. In these cases, I can again select the item and try to remove it a second time, then Flash Builder crashes because it is attempting to access an index value of -1 (`RangeError: Index '-1' specified is out of bounds.`). Any idea why this could happen?